# Save dialog box creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open save dialog box using file -> save option click in menu bar in J2ee web application. I am trying this code for opening save dialog box, but its not working.

```
<HTML>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div align=center id=Sect1>
<img Src='1.jpg' id=IMG1>
<p> This is some text</p>
</div>
<center>
<a href="\\172.16.2.1\ELSTest\Projects\QTS\Q0002\pdfviewer_src.zip"> pdfviewer_src.zip </a>
</center>
</body>
</HTML>
```

How to do this task? Please give me some code reference